# how to set length of input in ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs

I'm dealing with a phone number input validation with `ng-pattern`, When I refer some online sites I could see something like this

```
ng-pattern="/^\+?\d{0,1}?\d{1,10}$"
```

please tell me the meaning of this.

Answer (score 0):

That's a regular expression to validate that the input contains a phone number.  This is a good resource to understand it: https://regexr.com

Answer (score 0):

ng-minlength & ng-maxlength directives are useful for input length. refer this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-maxlength.asp